# BrokenPipeError inside gevent library when it is used with Celery. How to overcome the issue?

Tags: python, docker, rabbitmq, celery, gevent

We use `Celery` with `gevent` worker in our application. Workers are run as separated docker containers.

How we run Celery:
`celery -A app.worker worker --pool=gevent --loglevel=info --concurrency=50 -E -n woker-1 -Q some_q`

Once (sometimes more often) per day we get the following error:

```py
2023-04-14 05:06:11,023 ERROR celery.worker.consumer.consumer perform_pending_operations() L227  Pending callback raised: BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 225, in perform_pending_operations
    self._pending_operations.pop()()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vine/promises.py", line 160, in call
    return self.throw()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vine/promises.py", line 157, in call
    retval = fun(*final_args, **final_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/message.py", line 128, in ack_log_error
    self.ack(multiple=multiple)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/message.py", line 123, in ack
    self.channel.basic_ack(self.delivery_tag, multiple=multiple)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/amqp/channel.py", line 1407, in basic_ack
    return self.send_method(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/amqp/abstract_channel.py", line 70, in send_method
    conn.frame_writer(1, self.channel_id, sig, args, content)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/amqp/method_framing.py", line 186, in write_frame
    write(buffer_store.view[:offset])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 347, in write
    self._write(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/_socketcommon.py", line 699, in sendall
    return _sendall(self, data_memory, flags)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/_socketcommon.py", line 409, in _sendall
    timeleft = __send_chunk(socket, chunk, flags, timeleft, end)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/_socketcommon.py", line 338, in __send_chunk
    data_sent += socket.send(chunk, flags)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/_socketcommon.py", line 722, in send
    return self._sock.send(data, flags)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

From traceback I see that the error comes from `"/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/_socketcommon.py"`

I found this issue in [Github Issue#3377](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3377) , but it is related to another part of the code (older version of Celery), though it is also related to gevent library.

I also found "modern" version of the problem [Github Issue#7888](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/7888) . The issue states that the problem was not actually solved in [Github Issue#3377](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3377)

Container (with `Celery` worker inside) does not stops, but it stops doing it's work, connetion with RabbitMQ is broken and the worker does nothing.

How to overcome the issue?

**Possible walkaround:**

I guess that we can restart container every 1 hour with the help of some bash scripting + orchestrator logic. But I would like to have more robust solution, since the issue can presumably happen more often than once per day + restart is done "manually" rather than to some error.

**My (not the best) solution:**

Some bash script (you can add commands `python ...` or `celery ...` inside the block to run your python application)

```bash
# some pseudo python app code
declare -i n=0

while [ $n -lt 15 ]
do
    d=$(date)
    n=n+1
    echo $d Step: $n
    sleep 2
done
# some sleeping after it, then exit

exit 0  # the most important is to exit after n minutes of sleeping
```

Docker-compose file:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  xyz:
    image: xyz:latest
    container_name: xyz
    hostname: xyz
    restart: always  # always restart app despite no errors - code 0
```

Just some random Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8

RUN mkdir -p /my_super_app
COPY ./app /my_super_app/app

WORKDIR /my_super_app

# celery-worker starts inside the bash script
CMD ["bash", "/bgate-smev/app/worker-start.sh"]
```